# Add pandas Series to a DataFrame, preserving index

Tags: python, pandas

I have been having some problems adding the contents of a pandas Series to a pandas DataFrame. I start with an empty DataFrame, initialised with several columns (corresponding to consecutive dates).

I would like to then sequentially fill the DataFrame using different pandas Series, each one corresponding to a different date. However, each Series has a (potentially) different index.

I would like the resulting DataFrame to have an index that is essentially the union of each of the Series indices.

I have been doing this so far:

```
for date in dates:
     df[date] = series_for_date
```

However, my df index corresponds to that of the first Series and so any data in successive Series that correspond to an index 'key' not in the first Series are lost.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Ben

Comment: So are you wanting it to align to the `df.index`? it should work if you convert the series to a list: `df[date] = list(series_for_date)`

Comment: have you tried `join` or `merge`?

Comment: provide a short (like, 2 series, 10 entries each) set of sample data and the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you can use `concat`:

```
pd.concat([series1,series2,series3],axis=1)
```